# Adding Border to Image Widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm new to dart/flutter and trying to add a small black border around this image widget but I’m not sure how to.

code:

```
Align(
  alignment: const Alignment(0.0, -0.15),
  child: image.isNotEmpty
      ? Image.asset(
          image,
          width: 400,
          height: 200,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )
      : SizedBox.shrink(),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Container` with `DecorationImage`.

```dart
Container(
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      width: 2,
    ),
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      image: AssetImage(image),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: At what point do I wrap the rest of it within the container item?

Comment: you need to  replace `Image.asset(` with this